# Indonesia - Suggestion for mobile data provider

Tags: indonesia, mobile-operators

Planning to visit Jakarta, Indonesia soon.
I have heard that the mobile coverage there is quiet bad, even for the big city like Jakarta and Bali.
Therefore, I would like to know at least which one is the most recommended (as in the stable up time) in that country, and why.
Is it easy to get one upon arrival at the airport ?

Answer (score 3):

I bought a Sim Card in Bali with Indosat, the rate was 300k Rupiah (20 USD) for 7GB Data and some call allowances. I would suggest you just ask for somewhere local to buy a local sim and take their recommendation.

I found the coverage to be excellent across Bali, Seminyak and Ubud and on a par with anywhere I have visited in Europe.

You can buy at the airport too (Which has free wifi) but just pick a larger operator like I did.

The three biggest operators seem to be;

- Indosat
- XL Axiata
- Telkomsel

Answer (score 2):

I have bought SIM from Airport Klook office. (It is on the right side as soon as you come out from arrival gate). They offered tourist SIM at $16 - 9 GB 4G data (8 GB + 1 GB Youtube) and 15 min Talk time. It was XL Axiata.

Offline maps (from Google) will work fine for famous places. However, you will need data plan to search secluded places. In case, you are exploring all places so you will be needing around 70-90 MB per day (assuming that few other applications will use data too). I recommend you to uninstall applications which are not in use and can consume data.

It has complete coverage. Never lost connection; even while island hoping and even on ships while traveling from Nusa to Gill.

**Disclaimer**: I am neither working for or promoting klook. This answer is from my personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

There are several providers in Indonesia but the 3 biggest providers with national coverage and definitely covers all big/major cities in Indonesia are :
1. Telkomsel (Brands : Simpati, Kartu As, Flash)
2. Indosat (now called IM3 Ooredoo)(Brands : IM3)
3. XL Axiata (know also as XL)

For Prepaid, they are all equally good coverage and services
For Postpaid, I would recommend Telkomsel or Indosat. XL Customer Service is not that good.